# Fixing document path during PDF export from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-path

The document path on the side of my map changes when I export to PDF. 
The text says: "dyn type="document" property="path"
It displays the filepath correctly when I'm editing the document (maps are located on a shared server). 
However, when I export it to a PDF, in the PDF it shows the file as being in a temp folder on my local hard drive, a folder which doesn't even exist.

Why does the filepath switch when exported and how do I fix this?